# Visual Studio error when trying to find my database

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, visual-studio-2008, web-applications

I am a student learning asp.net and I ran into a problem when trying to reconfigure data sources I created.  When I run my web application I am able to edit/add/delete entries that are in my database but when I try to create or reconfigure a datasource it gives me this message:

> Database schema could not be retrieved for this connection. Please 
>   make sure the connection settings are correct and that the database is
>   online.
>
> Could not load file or assembly 
>   ‘Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Sdk.Sfc, Version=10.0.0.0, Culture=
>   neutral, PublicKey Token=89845dcd8080cc91’ or one of its 
>   dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.

Now I never changed the place of the database on my computer and I have never deleted it from the originating folder. I went into my 'Sever Explorer' tab and it shows that the database is connected. I right clicked on my database in the data connections list and went to 'Modify Connection...' and ran the 'Test Connection' option and it says the "Test connection succeeded". If my application can edit the database why can't Microsoft Visual Studio find the connection to let me edit the datasource?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the error indicated that the problem was the system cannot locate the right assembly  (`SQL Server SDK`).

I suspect that the installation of your `SQL Server` is not a complete or a successful one, or you should have to download some components to provide a successful connection.

Useful links with components that you would consider downloading [here](http://blogs.cametoofar.com/post/cannot-load-file-or-assembly-microsoftsqlservermanagementsdksfc.aspx) or [here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/vssetup/thread/5abfbb57-dac9-4039-b121-ae21c9b9352c)

Comment: Hey thanks for that fix, it solved the initial problem.  When I installed those files I was then able to edit/create SQLdatabases but I encountered another problem, my edit/insert/delete functions would not work and my pre-existing database was not showing up in data connections under the server explorer tab.  It wouldn't let me make changes to the database because the database was currently being used by another program.  In order to fix this I had to restart my computer in safe mode and delete my SQLEXPRESS folder. When I did this I was able to re-establish the connection to my database.